# Cypher select vertices whose any neighbours do not contain a property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

```
{
    "identity": 7,
    "labels": [
        "Parent"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "foo1"
    }
}, 
{
    "identity": 8,
    "labels": [
        "Child"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "bar2"
    }
}, 
{
    "identity": 9,
    "labels": [
        "Child"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "bar1"
    }
}, 
{
    "identity": 10,
    "labels": [
        "Parent"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "foo2"
    }
}
```

I want to select the **Parents** which do not have any **child** with `name='abc'`

Expected Behaviour : I should get both Parents (`foo1` and `foo2`) as result

Query1 :

```
Match (x1:Parent) with x1 
optional Match (x1)-[:CHILD]-(x2:Child) with x1 , collect(x2) as x3 
UNWIND x3 as x2 
WITH x1 , x2 , x3 
where none (x IN  x3 where x.name IN ['abc']) 
return DISTINCT x1
```

This query is returning me only 1 Parent(`foo1`) but it should return both parents and 2nd parent(`foo2`) is not connected to any child.

PS : Reason for using `UNWIND` is to use the variables for further `WHERE` clauses on variable `x2`.

Comment: When you read your data model, it reads Foo1 is Child of Bar1 and Bar2 which is the opposite. It should read Foo1 is a PARENT of Children Bar1 and 2.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to imply that foo1 and foo2 are parents, and bar1 and bar2 are actually children of foo1.

Comment: Then relationship name should be (:Parent) - [:HAS_CHILD] -> (:Child)

Comment: Yes correct  . It should be HAS_CHILD

Answer (score 0):

This will get all Parents without a child name: 'abc' or without any child

```
MATCH (p:Parent)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((p)-[:CHILD]->(:Child {name: 'abc'}))
RETURN p
```

> Check if the given parent, p has a child not named: 'abc'

==========
EDITED:

Personally I dislike this query because it is collecting x2 then unwinding it later. But for sake of answering the SO question,

```
Match (x1:Parent) with x1 
optional Match (x1)-[:CHILD]->(x2:Child) with x1 , collect({x1:x1, x2:x2}) as x3 
UNWIND x3 as x2 
WITH x2.x1 as x1, x2.x2 as x2, x3 
where NOT x2.name IN ['abc'] OR x2 is NULL 
RETURN distinct x1
```

> I collected BOTH x1 and x2 then UNWIND the collection by getting x1
> and x2 during unwind. This will include other nodes that has no x2
> (without a CHILD).  I also simplified the where condition because x2 is also accessible rather than looping again on x3

Comment: Reason for not doing that way is because I want to write  many complex queries on the child variable like age in between some range. And also I really want to know that what's wrong with my query

Comment: please give me the entire requirements, so that I can get the whole picture.

Comment: Try to change 'abc' with 'bar2' and your query would return foo1 also, which is not correct. It should return only foo2